# Message display on top of other apps

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Please help me in showing popup in front of browser. I have used following code, but it's coming behind browser once I clicked a save button.

```
JFrame frame;
frame = new JFrame("");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Instance is already created");
```

Comment: Why is the frame created?  Why does the option pane show method not specify a parent component?  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: i have no idea what you mean. None of this code seems relevnt to each other. Whats with the String? Doesn't seem to get used

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the window/frame as the first argument to show message dialog in front of that frame. So instead of passing null:

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Instance is already created");
```

pass the parent Frame

Comment: I don't think passing the frame as argument will help if that frame is not visible..